# Surefire maven plugin does not execute one of the tests

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a project with four packages. With three of them everything is fine. I have generated JUnit tests and they are executed during the build or while I am running mvn test command.
But my fourth package, containing just one class. I have created a JUnit test for it, but when I am running the build, Surefire does not see this test class. All other eight test classes are executed, but this one is ignored.
When I am trying to execute just this one test class explicitly using

> mvn -Dtest=com.company.dpt.prj.pkg.MySpecificClassTest test

I am getting these messages

```
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  16.058 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-12-19T23:58:01-08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project my-project-name: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I went through the test code line by line and couldn't find any reasons for such behavior.
I even deleted the test file and regenerated a very basic one. It is still not executed.
Has anyone encountered something similar? Any hint will be greatly appreciated, as I couldn't find any clues.
I am using JUnit 4.11

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
```

All tests were originally generated using Netbeans v.12 "Tools->Create/Update Test" and than edited to reflect methods functionality.
However, all test but this one are working fine both in Netbeans GUI and CLI "mvn test". This one is ignored. The purpose of method I want to test is to build HttpEntity for the REST API client. Here is the code of the test:

```
/**
 * Test of prepareRequest method, of class BatchServiceClient.
 * @throws java.net.URISyntaxException
 */
@Test
public void testPrepareRequest() throws URISyntaxException {
    System.out.println("prepareRequest");
    ObjectMapper mapper = Json.mapper();
    URL configFileUrl = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("config_f.json");
    if (configFileUrl == null) {
        fail("Missing configuration file");
    } else {
        File configFile = new File(configFileUrl.toURI());
        BatchConfig config = BatchConfigLoader.loadConfig(configFile);
        assertNotNull(config);
        boolean validated = config.validate();
        assertTrue(validated);
        BatchServiceClient client = new BatchServiceClient(config, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        List<Object> requestData = Arrays.asList("16759408", "", "", "", "The Home Depot", "",
                "Baltimore", "MD", "", "840", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 10, "",
                true, true, "merchantName", "merchantName", "merchantName");
        HttpEntity<String> request = client.prepareRequest(requestData);
        assertNotNull(request);
    }
}
```

My problem is that it is not failing within the test code. I will be happy if it would, because I will be able to debug it than. It is just not executing.
I tried to upgrade JUnit to v.4.13.1 and surefire maven plugin to v.3.0.0-M5 but it did not have any affect.

I tried to run mvn with -e option and got the following stack trace, but it still did not give me any clues on why it is happening.

```
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)

Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.reportExecution (SurefireHelper.java:149)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.handleSummary (SurefirePlugin.java:364)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1041)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:857)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

Comment: Could you add the test source and please specify Junit version and the relative path of the test.

Comment: Add full pom file and try `mvn -Dtest=MySpecificClassTest test` instead...

Comment: are you executing it via the command-line option or IntelliJ's GUI?

Comment: Does it execute if you just `mvn test`?

Comment: I said above that "mvn test" command executes 8 other tests but not this one. And it does not matter if I am specifying mvn -Dtest=MySpecificClassTest test or use fully qualified class name. Result is the same.

Comment: Just to try to isolate the cause. Does it get executed if you move this test method to the classes on the working packages? And, if you move any of the working test methods to this class?

Comment: I did copy/paste this test method to another file and it was ignored. However, it did help me finding the cause of the problem. Thank you Matheu.
See the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find the cause of the problem.
Somehow, when IDE generated (and regenerated) that test file it placed the wrong import for the @Test annotation. Instead of

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
```

it placed

```
import org.junit.Test;
```

Therefore, jupiter engine, ran by surefire did not recognized @Test annotation.
After I corrected import test was executed.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use this patter:

```
-Dtest=com.company.dpt.prj.pkg.MySpecificClassTest
```

because the Surefire and Failsafe plugin does not support fully qualified class name. It makes a lookup on the file system and therefore I showed you on how to use the slashes in the configuration. The documentation is specifying this option, read it again here:

**NOTE: Use syntax e.g. "foo/MyTest.java", "**/MyTest.java", "MyTest" for "test" parameter (see includes/excludes).**

Gary, your problem is that you are talking about the JUnit but which one? There are two versions 4 anf 5, and even more specifically you can post a source code to our Apache JIRA (or to Stackoverflow) and then me as a committer can have a look into your code. Really it cannot be reproduced without it because only a pure text in the stackoverflow cannot make your problem reproducible on my side. So please attach always a link the next time and we will have a look. One guy did it last week and it was very helpful.

Regarding the import of the Test annotation, it was not Surefire plugin that did not recognize the @Test import. :-) Really, it was your fault you did not write proper source code **including the POM** and the compiler has compiled the code as it was even if you combine JUnit4 and JUnit5 in the **POM**. Then the Surefire triggered the JUnit libraries which are then responsible for recognizing the annotations - not the Surefire. The Surefire algorithm would prefer using JUnit5 if you combine JUnit4 and JUnit5-Jupiter and that's the reason why the annotation **org.junit.Test** was ignored because the Jupiter does not find it and Jupiter's annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in a Spring Boot Project together with the Maven Surefire plugin 3.0.0-M5. Spring Boot is providing dependencies for junit4 and junit5. Maven Surefire has a precedence when selecting a provider and is choosing junit5 first [if available](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html):

> if the JUnit 5 Platform Engine is present in the project
> use junit-platform
> if the JUnit version in the project >= 4.7 and the <<>> configuration parameter has ANY value
> use junit47 provider
> if JUnit >= 4.0 is present
> use junit4 provider
> else
> use junit3.8.1

All my test were junit4 test and hence no test were found to be executed. I have migrated all tests, look out in the documentation to find an option to set the provider, maybe there is any.

Answer (score -1):

Please see the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html).

In your case the command should become:

```
mvn -Dtest=com/company/dpt/prj/pkg/MySpecificClassTest.java test
```

Comment: I am afraid that you haven't read documentation with proper attention. In multiple examples it is mentioning class file, not Java source file:

>mvn -Dtest=TestCircle test

However, I did try to run it as you mentioned. Result was the same.

Comment: :-) I am telling you that you have to use the package if you want to run the specific class.